# Which of the following statements is true if HI is formed in the following reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

> Which of the following statements is true if HI is formed in the following reaction?
>
> $$\ce{H2(g) + I2(g) -> 2HI(g)}$$
>
> **a**. There are no collisions between the reactants in the reaction.
>
> **b**. All of the collisions between reactants have enough energy to overcome the activation energy.
>
> **c**. Some of the collisions between reactants have enough energy to overcome the reaction mechanism.
>
> **d**. Some of the collisions of the reactants have enough energy to overcome the activation energy.

I think it is **d** because I think it has enough energy to overcome the AE due to the equation, but I am not sure.

Comment: Why do you think D is correct? Please include that in the question as well. Welcome to our site!

Comment: I think it has enough energy to overcome the AE due to the equation.

Comment: @Athena You really can't judge the AE by looking at the equation; but option d is still a safe bet,as per the modern collision theory.

Comment: Yes i know the equation is not the safest but im wondering is that how you would answer it? If not can you teach me why not. Thank you

Comment: Both B and  D can be true, C does not make sense; 'energy to overcome reaction mechanism' is nonsense. So the question is ambiguous, B, D could each lead to product